# Module has no exported member NumpadTouchControl

Tags: angularjs, typescript

I'm developing a custom directive with Angular 1.4.9 & TypeScript. The directive is done, but I'm trying to import it in my app.ts, so I can register it. This is where I'm stuck.

My directive looks likes this

```
export module Helloworld{
    export class NumpadTouchControl implements ng.IDirective{

    }
}
```

My app.ts like this

```
import { NumpadTouchControl } from './directives/numpadTouchControl';

module Helloworld {

}
```

On the first line of my app.ts it says: Module ... has no exported member 'NumpadTouchControl'. How can I make my import work?

I am not using webpack or browserify.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the outer `export module HelloWorld{`. Each file is implicitly a module.

If your first file is just

```
export class NumpadTouchControl implements ng.IDirective{
    ...
}
```

that should take care of it.

Comment: When I do this, the error is gone, but at runtime I get three errors:
Uncaught ReferenceError: exports is not defined
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Comment: For running your code in a browser you need to either include a module loader like systemjs or bundle your code using something like browserify.

Comment: I've just used browserify and it worked like a charm, thanks!